# Patching a hole in concrete/stucco wall

Tags: stucco, patch

We are having house re-piped and the plumbers removed gas water heater. It sits in the closet outside the house, and the closet is finished (?) with some sort of stucco or concrete mix. Plumber had to cut into that finish.

How can I fix it up? Should we spend a bit more time and remove all the stucco and refinish the whole closet with cement board or something else?

The house has shingle on the outside.

[image]

Comment: Your second question isn't for us to answer. It's entirely a matter of your prerogative. If you just need help patching stucco, that's been covered a few times already. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92714/how-to-fix-a-through-hole-in-stucco-on-the-outside-of-the-house, https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92714/how-to-fix-a-through-hole-in-stucco-on-the-outside-of-the-house and https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145982/patch-small-holes-in-an-internal-stucco-wall, for example.